# Set div height dynamically using inline CSS and invoking a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For my purposes, I need to set the div height as quickly as possible.

Using the `document.ready()` event is not fast enough, so I want to set the inline CSS style of the div.

How can achieve something like this?

```
<div id="map-container" style="height:javascript(getwindowheight)px;">
    <div id="map">

    </div>
</div>

function getwindowsheight() {
    return window.height;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not just use height:100% ? Just remember the parent container of #map-container also needs a height for this to work.

Comment: Styles belong in CSS. Do you have a *really* good reason for using JS?

Comment: @ComputerArts: It's turtles all the way up? :P - map-container is the most top level div, that's why I want to give it a specific pixel based height.

Comment: But you're returning window.height so I'm guessing you want the div to fill the screen from top to bottom. If you set html and body to height:100%, map-container will stretch the entire screen.

Comment: @ComputerArts: That is correct. That's the code I had before posting this question and it caused some weird results, which I hypothesized were being caused by not having a div wrapped around `#map` I used `#map, body, html { height: 100%; }`- turns out that's not the case I'll be posting another question soon.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vMvsj/ here's an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want it to be dynamic, you will need to pay attention to the following events:

- window resize
- window ready

Set your HTML first:

```
<div id="map-container"></div>
```

And then inside your JavaScript, setup a function to detect those:

```
var applyMapContainerHeight = function() {
  var height = $(window).height();
  $("#map-container").height(height);
};

document.ready(function() {
  applyMapContainerHeight();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  applyMapContainerHeight();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided that jQuery is script files are included in the very beginning of your HTML, place some scripting right after the `div` declaration:

```
<div id="map-container">
    <div id="map">

    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#map-container").height(getwindowsheight());
    function getwindowsheight() {
        return window.height;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Won't this return $ is not defined? Jquery might not be loaded yet.

Comment: @ComputerArts Usually, external js links are defined at the beginning of the HTML. And they should. I just updated the answer to make sure that's the case.

Comment: Not necessarily, I've been seeing more and more javascript files being included at the bottom of the body so that the page (the text) renders faster (without having to wait for all the js libraries to load).

Comment: There is no need of using jquery here, plain javascript will be better.

Answer (score 0):

Then don't use document.ready

just execute your js after div

```
<div id="map-container">
    <div id="map">

    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#map-container').css({ height: 'your height'});
</script>
```

Comment: it will work if you added link to jQuery in your head section.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="map-container">
    <div id="map">
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("map-container").style.height= $(window).height() + "px";
</script>
```